# Should my DNS server and DHCP server have the same IP address?

Tags: ip

trying to resolve a 'Server not Found' error message. If I reload the page a few times it works.. So I went to the Event Viewer and saw my DNS timed out, went to CMD did the ol' ipconfig /all to see my IP address and I noticed that the DNS server and DHCP server had the same IP address.. should I be concerned or is that normal (bit of a networking beginner so go easy)?

Also if anyone has a resolution on how to fix the DNS thing could you comment and not answer? I'd like the answers to do with my question :)

Comment: Too little informations. Which event viewer? the server's or the client's? Have you tried nslookup? Did you check your firewall rules, and eventually tried to disable it completely (before you ask I'll say that yes, Windows builtin firewall sometimes goes nuts)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not unusual on a small network to provide both of these functions from the same server.  It's not a problem unless you had reason to expect DNS to be provided by a different system, in which case check the configuration of the DHCP server.

Comment: I'd also add that, since he seems to have a MS Windows environment, that's pretty much the rule as a server with Active Directory will have both the dhcp server and the the dns server roles automatically installed on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

If your DNS and DHCP services are on the same server, that is not a problem. If these are on different machines, it could be that you have an IP address conflict in which case you must change the IP of one of your servers.

About the DNS service itself, do you have anything in your Event Viewer ? What does an nslookup return ?